# Why does keyof yield a union of properties rather than an intersection of properties?

Tags: typescript

Using `keyof` with the following type yields a `union` of property names:

```
type Person = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    location: string;
}

type K1 = keyof Person; // "name" | "age" | "location"
```

Similarly, if I use the `Omit` helper that leverages `Exclude`, I must provide a `union` of properties for `keyof T` where intuitively I'd *expect* to provide an `intersection` of properties to be omitted but that's not the case:

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
type PersonName = Omit<Person, "location" | "age">;  
// type Person = { name: string }
```

I'd think from my understanding, it would be the following instead which is the composition of the `type` as it requires the `intersection` of all properties and not the `union` of the properties:

```
// This isn't valid, but what I'd expect using keyof
type K1 = keyof Person; // "name" & "age" & "location"
type PersonName = Omit<Person, "location" & "age">;
```

When it comes to `keyof`, where am I off in my understanding of the properites yielded as a `union` as opposed to an `intersection` of the property keys for that `type`? The `type` can't exist with each property being an *either* scenario as a `union` describes. The `type` isn't valid unless it's the `intersection` of all `properties` correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The type can't exist with each property being an either scenario as a union describes.

`keyof T` does not describe type `T`, it describes a type for possible keys that can be used to get properties of `T`, that is, a type for `key` variable in the expression `t[key]` where `t` value has type `T`. This is the type system for javascript, after all, where property access `t.propertyName` is exactly the same as slightly more elaborated `t["propertyName"]`, and the latter has always allowed accessing object properties dynamically using a variable that holds a property name.

It's a union type because you can use any single key in the `t[key]` expression.

Intersection of literal types just does not make sense - type  `"name" & "age" & "location"` means that a variable value is equal to all three literal values at the same time, which is impossible. Internally such intersections are reduced to `never` type.

Comment: `type  "name" & "age" & "location" means that a variable value is equal to all three literal values at the same time, which is impossible` Excellent for helping me clear this up, thank you. I knew I was off in my understanding.